# MATLAB Code error

Tags: matlab, list, element

Below is my MATLAB function, and it contain some error, so wish any expert can correct or point out the mistake and way to improve it. I using MATLAB R2015a

```
function L = remove_all(L,E)
% remove_all(List,element) - delete all occurrences of E from L
for Index = length(L.elements):-1:1
    if isequal(E,L.elements{Index})
        L.elements(Index) = [];
    end 
end
```

Comment: We aren't mind readers. **What exactly is the error MATLAB gives you?**  Please also give the expected inputs and outputs.  For one thing, I have no idea what `L` contains, and what the field `elements` is supposed to contain.

Comment: Agreed, the question would be much better if you edited it to explain what you expected to see and what you actually do see.

Comment: What is the error did you get...? Please mention it in the post.

Comment: So did any of us help you?

Answer (score 2):

You are mutating the structure in the `for` loop by removing elements in this structure but forgetting the fact that the length of the structure changes as you are removing elements.  As such, the length of the structure **decreases** with each removal, and you will eventually go out of bounds when removing items.  Specifically, you used `length` to capture the initial length of the list, but as you are removing items, this length is no longer the same and the `for` loop is not cognizant of that fact.  Therefore, you will eventually get an out-of-bounds error due to this erroneous removing of items.

A way to resolve this would be to save all of the locations that are to be removed from the structure and when the `for` loop is done, remove them all at once:

```
function L = remove_all(L,E)
% remove_all(List,element) - delete all occurrences of E from L
indices = []; %// New - keep the locations that need to be removed
for Index = length(L.elements):-1:1
    if isequal(E,L.elements{Index})
        indices = [indices; Index]; %// Add to list if equal
    end 
end
L.elements(indices) = []; %// Remove all entries at once
```

Answer (score 2):

Although rayryeng's answer pointed out the mistake and corrected it, but i still want to try a 1-line-code version with `cellfun`:

```
function L = remove_all(L,E)
% remove_all(List,element) - delete all occurrences of E from L
L.elements(cellfun(@(x) x == E, L.elements)) = [];
end
```

Comment: Curious to see how this compares in performance with the `for` loop.  `cellfun` essentially is a loop underneath the hood... but very good :)